# How to turn off or terminate my Django app when I click the button on browser

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and Django, now I want to ask about how to turn off or terminating my Django app when I click button on my browser.

On the browser, I click the button and then sending post request to the server using javascript fetch api.

On the server when I sending the POST request, i'm executing `exit()` command, but it doesn't kill my Django app.

Is there a way to kill my Django app?

Comment: Why do you want to do something so insecure? What if someone who is not you somehow is able to access this button and decides that they want to shut down your website for malicious purposes? Refrain from writing such code. It is not hard to close the website yourself.

Comment: It's a installer interface, so when the installations completed i can turn off my installer app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solutions, I can kill the app by using this command

```
os.system('pkill python')
```

thanks.

Comment: This is sheer brilliance...